# How to create an excel column that will flag dates that have passed or are upcoming

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatable

I have an column in a table that is full of dates. I am trying to create another column that will flag/label label each of the dates based on if they are upcoming or have already passed

This is what I have so far, and this same formula will go down the entire column (AW3,AW4,etc..) but I'm pretty sure I have some syntax errors

```
=
IF(ISBLANK(AW2),"NO DEADLINE",
IF(AW2="N/A"),"NO DEADLINE",
IF(AW2<=TODAY()),"DATE PASSED",
IF(AW2>TODAY()),"UPCOMING",))))
```

Comment: Instead: `=
IF(ISBLANK(AW2),"NO DEADLINE",
IF(AW2="N/A","NO DEADLINE",
IF(AW2<=TODAY(),"DATE PASSED",
IF(AW2>TODAY(),"UPCOMING"))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parentheses are a bit off and there's a lone comma on the end. Using some tabs usually helps find these little mistakes:

```
=
IF(ISBLANK(AW2),"NO DEADLINE",
    IF(OR(ISNA(AW2), AW2 ="N/A"),"NO DEADLINE",
        IF(AW2<=TODAY(),"DATE PASSED",
            IF(AW2>TODAY(),"UPCOMING", "Exception"))))
```

Comment: If I also wanted to change it so "Upcoming" dates would be within 1 week from TODAY and anything beyond one week would be "FUTURE DEADLINES" would I do IF(AND(AZ2<=TODAY()+7,AZ2>=TODAY()),"UPCOMING",
IF(AZ2>TODAY()+7),"FUTURE DEADLINES",))))

Comment: The IF statements work in succession, so you can make it even shorter: `IF(ISBLANK(AW2),"NO DEADLINE",
IF(OR(ISNA(AW2), AW2 ="N/A"),"NO DEADLINE",
IF(AW2<=TODAY(),"DATE PASSED",
IF(AW2<=TODAY() + 7,"UPCOMING", 
"FUTURE DEADLINES"))))`